# How to specify column type in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, apply

After executing this line

```
data['numbers'] = data.apply(lambda row : [1] * len(row.text), axis=1)
```

The column 'numbers' is not a list as I expect it to be, but instead it's of type object which can't be indexed and I get IndexError.

What I want as result is a column with 'numbers' where each line has as much ones as the length of the corresponding text in the line.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dtype` of `string`s, `dict`s, `list`s, `set`s, `tuple`s is always `object`, for testing `type` use:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'text':['aaas','as']}, index=[10,12])

data['numbers'] = data.apply(lambda row : [1] * len(row.text), axis=1)

print (data['numbers'].apply(type))
0    <class 'list'>
1    <class 'list'>
Name: numbers, dtype: object

#check scalar
print (type(data.loc[0, 'numbers']))
<class 'list'>
```

If want check `length`s:

```
print (len(data.iloc[0, data.columns.get_loc('numbers')]))
4

data['lens'] = data['numbers'].str.len()
print (data)

    text       numbers  lens
10  aaas  [1, 1, 1, 1]     4
12    as        [1, 1]     2
```

Comment: If I convert the DataFrame to pandas Series then it's all OK, but if I try to iterate on it then I get indexError:
for e.g.:
len(data.iloc[0]['numbers']) = 1 which can't be true, because after converting it to series it's a list with 2000 elements

Comment: @Zarrie - Can you show me your code with `indexError` ?

Comment: So what return `print (len(data.iloc[0]['numbers']))` ?

Comment: I can't share the code as it is part of a project, and the error itself is like few hundred lines, so I'll assume that I have to deal with it alone. Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: print (len(data.iloc[0]['numbers'])) prints 1
I see that actually printing the data.iloc[0]['numbers'] is 
array([list([1,1,1,1,1....,1,1,1])]) Is this the problem?

Comment: hmmm, so code for `numbers` is not `data['numbers'] = data.apply(lambda row : [1] * len(row.text), axis=1)`, right?

Comment: It seems there are nested lists, so what about `print (type(data.iloc[0]['numbers'][0]))` ?

Comment: Actually this is the exact code for applying the function. After `print(type(data.iloc[0]['numbers'][0]))` I get `<class 'int'>`

Comment: If use my test sample DataFrame, it return `array([list([1,1,1,1])])` ? What is your pandas version?

Comment: 0.22.0 is the version of my pandas

Comment: if use `print ((data.iloc[0]['numbers']))` in `DataFrame` in my answer, get `array([list([1,1,1,1])])` ? I cannot simulate it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I can't explain clear enough what my problem is.

Comment: @Zarrie - I was worried about it :( The best should be create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: After a lot of debugging i understood that because of the fact that some of my samples are NaN in the column, after saving it into csv and then reading it as first element, the column type is not corrects which leads to this strange behaviour. Thank you for your willing to help!